# Simple box with tabs

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented

While trying to become better in javascript I've written the following simple box with tabs:

Javascript: (entire code (HTML/CSS) is in the snippet)

```
var Test = {};

Test.Tabs = function (element) {

    this.tabBox = element;

    this.init = function() {
        var tabs = this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
        for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs[i].addEventListener(
                'click',
                (function (event) {
                    if(event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
                        return;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    this.toggle();
                }).bind(this),
                false
            );
        }
    };

    this.toggle = function() {
        this.hideAll();
        this.toggleClass(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
        this.show(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
    };

    this.hideAll = function() {
        var targets = this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('[id*=tab-]');
        for(var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            targets[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    this.toggleClass = function(id) {
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('.active')[0].classList.remove('active');
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('[href="'+id+'"]')[0].parentNode.classList.add('active');
    };

    this.show = function(id) {
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll(id)[0].style.display = 'block';
    };

    this.init();
};

(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-box'),
        function (element, index) {
            new Test.Tabs(element);
        }
    );
})();
```

```js
var Test = {};

Test.Tabs = function (element) {

    this.tabBox = element;

    this.init = function() {
        var tabs = this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
        for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs[i].addEventListener(
                'click',
                (function (event) {
                    if(event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
                        return;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    this.toggle();
                }).bind(this),
                false
            );
        }
    };

    this.toggle = function() {
        this.hideAll();
        this.toggleClass(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
        this.show(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
    };

    this.hideAll = function() {
        var targets = this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('[id*=tab-]');
        for(var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            targets[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    this.toggleClass = function(id) {
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('.active')[0].classList.remove('active');
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll('[href="'+id+'"]')[0].parentNode.classList.add('active');
    };

    this.show = function(id) {
        this.tabBox.querySelectorAll(id)[0].style.display = 'block';
    };

    this.init();
};

(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-box'),
        function (element, index) {
            new Test.Tabs(element);
        }
    );
})();
```

```css
.tabs-box {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}

.tabs-box nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid lime;
    border-right: 1px solid lime;
    border-left: 1px solid lime;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li.active {
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabs-box div[id*=tab-] {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs-box div[id*=tab-] ~ div[id*=tab-] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-box">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">1 Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">2 Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">3 Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <p>1 Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <p>2 Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <p>3 Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the questions are:

1. Do I need more properties so it would become better?
   (With better I mean performance and code maintainability. Like in the `init()` I could save all tabs and targets into properties, but then how to use them...)
2. Not sure how object-oriented this is. So how to make it fully object oriented?
3. Any thoughts in naming `variables`, `functions` and `properties` are welcome.

**OR altogether**, how would a javascript PRO write this simple task?

Comment: What level of browser support do you require? Would you be open to suggestions that involve ES6?

Comment: Hi @Shaggy thanks for your comment. ES6 has a little poor browser support at the moment. I wouldn't mind if it would be working at least in all common browsers such as IE10 and above, FF, Chrome and Safari. But actually just saying, it would be nice, but is no HAS TO BE. So long story short: I'm open to all all suggestions!

Comment: Are you aware of jQuery UI tabs? Why would you prefer writing custom code over jQuery?! A javascript PRO would definitely prefer jQuery.

Comment: @NisargShah Yes, I know jQuery. But I don't want to use it for many reasons. Especially in this case, cause I want to become better in javascript coding and understanding whats going on under the hood. So for me this is how to learn it.  `A javascript PRO would definitely prefer jQuery` I do not think so. JQuery is also just written in javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your questions**

> - Do I need more properties so it would become better? (With better I mean performance and code maintainability. Like in the init() I could save all tabs and targets into properties, but then how to use them...)

Performance can come from simplifying. Don't duplicate variables or functionality. Dont define functions that are only called once. Less is always better when programming.

Maintainability. The best code is written once and never ever touched again. Code that has a focus on *Maintainability* is code that is unfinished and untested.

Make your code readable, use correct names that reflect the state/s it 
represents, and keep to a consistent style. Test it thoroughly with the aim to make it crash. If you can not break it, it's finished.

> - Not sure how object-oriented this is. So how to make it fully object oriented?

You use objects so I guess its object-oriented. OO is a very loose term, some would argue javascript is not an OO language, other say it is. Personally I can not wait for OOP to disappear as an abused concept and more specific terms used like inheritance, encapsulation, modularity... and more.

> - Any thoughts in naming variables, functions and properties are welcome.

See below

**Notes on changes made.**

- "use strict"; Use it always..
- Declare variables and then functions at the top of the function. Also (not applicable in your code as you did not break this rule) for variables define/assign type/values only when needed and never where they are declared
- You are using `window.event` which is a very **non standard** object introduced by IE. Its behaviour can not be trusted and should not be used in a multi browser environment.
- Renamed `Tabs` to `tab` as it only handles a single tab.
- When you created your `tab` object you passed the argument `element`. Then you assign that element to the property `tabBox` this is just duplication and not needed the argument is closed over for all the functions in the `tab` object.
- AS you have not indicated a need for any type of interface (nor do you keep a referance to the object you create) there is no need to make its functions public. A safer approch is to protect all of its functionality by using closure.
- Too many functions for very minor amounts of code. This is inefficient. You create functions when you have code that is repeated, or need to provide specific interface functionality. So I have collapsed all the functions into two `toggle(ref)` and `tabClick(event)`
- You were creating a list of event handlers for each tab in a function `init()` The function is called only once during the instantiation. I could not see any reason for this to be a function. I moved it to inline.
- There is a rule in javascript **"DON'T  create functions inside conditional blocks"** loop blocks are conditional blocks. You were creating the anon event handler inside the loop that was iterating the tab elements. I moved the event handler out as a named function `tabClick`
- You used the variable `id` for the page referance link. Id is something else so I considered it as a bad name choice. I have called it `ref`
- Immediately invoked function are used to close over variables, or to create local scoped variables. If you are not closing over variables or creating any variables there is no need to use a immediately invoked function
- Don't use inline styles. When you hide and show the various elements for the tabs and content you should use a CSS defined rule rather than a inline rule. I did not change that as I don't want to touch the CSS

**Notes.**

I would redesign the way tab works by having it encapsulate all of the tabs. For each instance of tab you end up iterating all the tabs so why isolate them to begin with.

The `this` token should only be used to expose the interface. If there is no interface (such as your code) then there should be no reason to use `this` to referance any internal functionality or state.

**Code rewrite**

Some additional comments can be found in the code.

```js
"use strict"; // Never write code without this directive.
var Test = {};
// lower case tabs as it is no longer created with the new token
// It represents a tab not a group of tabs
Test.tab = function (tabBox) { // renamed argument from element to tabBox
    var tabs, i; // variables to the top
    function tabClick(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        // href returns full path so split at the # and get the last item
        toggle("#" + this.href
            .split("#")
            .pop()
        );
    }
    function toggle(ref) {
        var targets, i; // declare variables at top of function
        targets = tabBox.querySelectorAll('[id*=tab-]');
        for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            targets[i].style.display = 'none';  // would it not be better that
                                                // this be a CSS rule rather than
                                                // an inline style
        }
        // readability when chaining functions indent and separate into 
        // lines to make it easy to read
        tabBox
            .querySelector('.active') // Why use querySelectorAll. querySelector is more efficient
            .classList
            .remove('active');
        tabBox
            .querySelector('[href="' + ref + '"]')
            .parentNode
            .classList
            .add('active');
        tabBox
            .querySelector(ref)
            .style
            .display = 'block';  // should be a CSS rule not inline
    }
    // no need for the following to be in a function
    tabs = tabBox.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        // don't declare functions inside loops. tabClick is now a named function
        tabs[i].addEventListener('click', tabClick, false);
    }
};

// no need for immediate invocation
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-box'),
    Test.tab  // no need for anon function pass referance directly
);
```

```css
.tabs-box {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
}

.tabs-box nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid lime;
    border-right: 1px solid lime;
    border-left: 1px solid lime;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li.active {
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs-box nav ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabs-box div[id*=tab-] {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs-box div[id*=tab-] ~ div[id*=tab-] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-box">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">1 Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">2 Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">3 Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <p>1 Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <p>2 Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <p>3 Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your answer in general, but I disagree with * The best code is written once and never ever touched again.* In my experience, a good code can easily change. It does not have to change because it is flawed, but if someone wishes to extend it, it should be easy to do so.

Comment: @NisargShah That is new code. In my early career I would have agreed with your position. Now I am strongly against modifying finished projects. Finnish code must pass rigorous testing, a very expensive process. Changing just one line, one character in the source will negate all testing and require the full testing and acceptance cycle, not something the client will happily fork out for. Would you trust your life on a untested patch on any part of an autopilot system? Not all software is life critical, but quality assurance is for business, life.

Comment: It's debatable. I tend to lean towards maintainability because I work on a products that evolve with time. Hence the emphasis on ensuring that it is easy to modify the code I write. Maybe your work differs...

Comment: @NisargShah Yes agreed code quality is a very subjective quality.  From a business point of view, quality code is code that never needs change. If the customer requires more, we start again.  Sometime from the original core,  but mostly,  a complete ground up rewrite to allow us to improve upon from what we have learnt. Maintainability is the art of compromise,  to write to fit the existing unsupporting infrastructure, to guard against the unknown, to coerce functionality that was never intended. Every compromise diminishes quality, it is an insidious rot that destroys good code.

Comment: I do agree that the tendency to `guard against the unknown` is something to watch out for. But that is not an argument to not emphasize on maintainability. What if the change is very small - like a single line of code - you'd say rewriting the code is not a good choice in that case. What if the code to be added is 10 lines - you might reluctantly agree to add that as well. So when do you really decide that the code should be built from scratch? 100 lines? 1000 lines? It is going to differ from person to person. Also, is it reasonable to write 60k lines from scratch to add another 1k?

Comment: @NisargShah If your code is flawed and needs to be fixed, it is not the best code is it. If the customer wants change, they must pay for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48791/discussion-between-nisarg-shah-and-blindman67).

Comment: @NisargShah Thanks for the invite but I am a little too busy for chat ATM..